# Kafka stream app with internal rocksdb state store not able to get the data back for a key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, stream-processing

I have a kafka stream app running with 36 different instance (one for each partition). And I am building rest service on top of the state to access the data.

Here some code to access the data

```
StreamsMetadata metadata = streams.metadataForKey(store, key, serializer); --> call this find ouy which host has the key
if (localSelf.host().equals(hostStoreInfo.getHost())) {
get the key from local store
}
else {
call the remote host using restTemplate
```

The problem now is `metadata` object returned has a different host/ip but the data is on a different node. I was able to see using some application logs I printed.

The `allMetadata` method on `KafkaStreams` says the value will be update as when the partition get reassigned. But its not happening in case. What could I do.

Comment: If you can reproduce reliable, please file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks I have reported the issue here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7640